# Created a Site with Zurb Foundation. Converted into Wordpress theme, now links are broken

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation-5

Any amount of help here would be amazing, I'm at my wit's end. I've been trying to figure this out for about 9 hours.

I have a finished site that I built using Zurb foundation. There is some additional javascript, but there is an appropriate js file for that.

I added the index.php, footer.php, and header.php in order to convert the site into a wordpress site. However, upon installing the theme, all links are broken with regard to the js, css, and images. I would LOVE any kind of help.

The finished site should APPEAR like this (code is not the same):
http://brookeseggleston.tribaldroid.com/zfbrookeseggleston/index.html

but currently looks like this:http://69.195.124.159/~brooket7/

Thank you!

Comment: Does the `/img/` folder exist and contain the images? As that is where browser is looking for them

Comment: It does, but it's looking for an absolute path instead of the path relative to the theme, which is really annoying, I hope I don't need to add an absolute path to every image...

Comment: Besides the image path, though, nothing is connected, including js and css

Comment: you need to use relative urls. If you view the page source you will see every link is incorrect. use wp functions like `get_site_url()' to get the correct url to your server. If that doesnt work check the values you inputted into wordpress for addresses etc. BTW relative urls also work but will be in relation to the file calling them. Some times its just easier to create a php constant for image / js folders and use that to construct the url, if you ever move a file you'll see the value of this.

Comment: Thank you so much David, that's actually working now. I'll look into making php constants for the next site, because it will help make all this easier.